# Is Auth.js compatible with Sveltekit SSR?

Tags: authorization, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I am trying to create a Sveltekit app where users can log in. The login process is handled by a self-created API, so I would like to use the Auth.js Credentials Provider.
When I call the SignIn method as the FormAction in the +page.server.ts file, I get the error message 'window is not defined', which makes sense. Does this mean that Auth.js is not compatible with server-side rendering, or is there something else that I can adjust?

My Code:

```js
//hooks.server.ts
SvelteKitAuth({
        providers: [
            // @ts-ignore
            Credentials({
                name: "credentials",
                async authorize(credentials, req) {
                    // TODO: Call Api
                    const user = { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

                    if (user) {
                        return user
                    } else {
                        return null
                    }
                }
            })
        ],
    });
```

```js
//+page.server.ts
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ cookies, request }: { cookies: any, request: any }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const credentials = {
            username: data.get('username'),
            password: data.get('password')
        };

        signIn('credentials', credentials)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Success');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('error', error);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a workaround, but when I tried Auth.js myself in my own app, it just doesn't seem to work, so instead I used SvelteKitAuth made by Vercel. https://vercel.com/blog/announcing-sveltekit-auth

Comment: The question seems to be about the same `SvelteKitAuth` (`@auth/sveltekit/client`) as the one introduced in the vercel blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@auth/sveltekit/client`'s `signIn()` is [documented](https://authjs.dev/reference/sveltekit/client#signin) as a "**Client-side** method to initiate a signin flow[...]", and one of the devs [recently confirmed](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7098) there's no official support for server-side use yet.